# Spring Security and CORS requests

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security, cors, authorization

I have a rest api in java with spring boot 3.1.3. I have spring security too. I also have a website with react (both running locally on my computer).

I am trying to make a request to my api from the front with **fetch** but the headers in the request to my api would not be arriving, in particular the Authorization header.

My **controller** is the following:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> userAccess() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse("User Content."));
    }
}
```

I configured my **WebSecurityConfig** configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler, CorsConfig corsConfig) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                                auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

Also add a **WebConfiguration** and a **CorsFilter**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Authorization");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // not needed
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //not needed
    }
}
```

From javascript i make my request like this:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/test/user", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The error I end up getting is this:

`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/test/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

In my **AuthTokenFilter** (extends OncePerRequestFilter) I see null when I want to access the headers

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
      @Override
      protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    }
}
```

I tried different settings for **cors** and still have the same problem. When I access the endpoint from **Postman** everything works correctly.

Comment: why have you written a custom CorsFilter when spring security already has full support for CORS, and it is enabled by default? Also you are aware that handing out JWTs to browsers is insecure and thats why there is no implementation for it in spring security, so why have you decided to build something that is very insecure?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Why would "handing out JWTs to browsers" be insecure?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdGOb7AxUo0&t=1s

Comment: @Toerktumlare I had already watched Randall's talk and I'm unmoved by his arguments. The only valid criticisms among Randall's many objections to (stateless) JWTs is the impossibility to revoke them. Outright claiming that "handing out JWTs to browsers is insecure" is simply misleading.

Comment: then i suggest you do some more research, oauth2 has deprecated the implicit flow, storing sensitive information in local storage is discouraged by owasp like tokens, handing out JWTs, open id connect hands out cookies as they have features like HttpOnly, Secured and SameSite which are there to protect you from XSS, Token Replay. I dont care if you agree or not, but you can have that argument instead with OWASP, the authors of Oauth2 and several others in the security community, because im not going to argue with you in comments. Good day

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).